# Reminder Application using CalendarView in Android

Tags: android, android-alarms, android-calendar

I have developed Reminder application using the normal GregorianCalendar for my application. And i Create the Reminder using DatePicker and TimePicker..

While the Reminder Time Reached, the Alarm will be started and one Alert Message will be Poped-up. I have used the Following codes for this process..

```
Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.DA");
operation = PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(),0,i,Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
calendar = new GregorianCalendar(y, m, d,hr, mi);
alarm_time = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,alarm_time,operation);
```

In this i have create an intent for the Alarm Process..

By using the `alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,alarm_time,operation);` line i can catch the Alarm/Reminder which is in Present..

I couldn't get any Reminder of Past Time, while i had switched off my Tablet and Switch on after a long time..

The Reminders in that time period were not been seen by me. How could i rectify this Problem...

And suggest the way to proceed this by Using the CalendarView options instead of using DatePicker and TimePicker...

Comment: are you storing your event data in content values ?

Comment: friend the reminder which have gone are not alerting or you are not able to see the saved reminder?

Comment: Varun  your comment is for who me or Gowri shankar ?

Comment: Reminder couldn't Alerting. Because in this code i have used (AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,alarm_time,operation).. So it wakes-up the Alarm for the Present time only while the Tablet is Switched on only.. It's not Working in the Offline or Switched off time..

Comment: You can reset the Past Reminder for the Current Time

Answer (score 2):

Once you switched off your phone, your all customized alarms will erased , to overcome this you need to add boot permission in your app , by whenever your phone gets rebooted then a BroadCastReciever will execute from where you can again set your saved alarms, if alarm time has been crossed then all pending alarms will automatically goes on.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<receiver android:name=".YourReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Comment: i'm not using the System's Database.. I have Separate Database for Storing the Reminders

Comment: How the Pending alarms to be notified to the Display.. The time crossed Alarms need to be Display in my Screen.. How can i achieve this..

Comment: pending executed will be executed for alarms which have crossed time,whatever intent which need to be executed when alarms goes on will be excuted.

Comment: if time has passed and your alarm is active somehow then once the phone is on, and you have set the same, pending intent will execute

Comment: But Maneesh, i couldn't catch your's Point